# Flutter: Encrypt and Decrypt downloaded image

Tags: android, encryption, flutter, dart

I am able to download the image using

```
Future downloadImage({imageUrl, String imageName, type}) async {

  await get(imageUrl).then((res) async {
    if (res.statusCode == 200) {
      var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

      File file = new File(join(documentDirectory.path, imageName));

      file.writeAsBytesSync(res.bodyBytes);
      showLog('image file name ${documentDirectory.path.toString()}');

      showLog('image file name1 ${file.path.toString()}')
    }
 });
}
```

how to encrypt the downloaded image and decrypt it while using

Comment: Where are you going to get the key and derive the IV assuming some sort of block based cipher?

Comment: Key would be a random one or have to obtain from api. Not at all planned about the key thanks @RichardHeap

Comment: The cipher bit is the easy part - just use a `pointycastle` block cipher (or one of the authenticating ciphers in its forks). You can't just think about encryption without considering the generation/storage of the key/IV.